# TF-Ranking transform data to ELWC - ExampleListWithContext form

Tags: tensorflow, ranking

I have read all the guides, videos, and everything, but I have no idea how to convert my feature set to an ELWC datasheet format for TF-Rank ListWise problem. There is no description of this structure.

For example, a students profile is:

```
Student ID  age  grade  math%   physics%   english%  art%  math_competit  language_competit Rank
  14588     16    k12     98      67         88      100   first_place        very_good       5
```

If I have 20 students in the same class, how can I transform this data to be able to make a listwise prediction for every grade ( theoretically in every grade has 3 class with 20 students)

Answer (score 8):

ELWC format requires 'context' and 'example features'. Example features are features that are different for every item in a query list. Context features are ones which are dependent only on the query.
Therefore, every query will have a list of features for every item in the list (the Example features), and a single list of features for Context features.

To convert to ELWC format, start by gathering all the items for a given query. The code below shows a query with two items along with some context information. Use `input_pb2.ExampleListWithContext()` to create an instance of a ELWC formatter. Then all you have to do is feed in the context and examples.

Save using `TFRecordWriter`.

```
from tensorflow_serving.apis import input_pb2
import tensorflow as tf

def _float_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=[value]))


def _int64_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))


def _bytes_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))

context = {
    'custom_features_1': _float_feature(1.0),
    'utility': _int64_feature(1),
}
examples = [
        {
            'custom_features_1': _float_feature(1.0),
            'custom_features_2': _float_feature(1.5),
            'utility': _int64_feature(1),
        },
        {
            'custom_features_1': _float_feature(1.0),
            'custom_features_2': _float_feature(2.1),
            'utility': _int64_feature(0),
        }
]


def to_example(dictionary):
    return tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=dictionary))

ELWC = input_pb2.ExampleListWithContext()
ELWC.context.CopyFrom(to_example(context))
for expl in examples:
    example_features = ELWC.examples.add()
    example_features.CopyFrom(to_example(expl))

print(ELWC)
```